# Unit-testing superclass

Tags: unit-testing, swift, xctest

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite the following *Objective-C* unit-test in *Swift*:

```
- (void)testSuperclass {
    Class superclass = [self.animatedView superclass];
    Class expectedSuperclass = [BREAnimatedView class];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(superclass, expectedSuperclass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
func testSuperclass() {
    XCTAssert(self.animatedView is BREAnimatedView)
}
```

It's slightly different than your original condition, which tests if `BREAnimatedView` is the *direct* superclass of the view, whereas this just tests if the view inherits from `BREAnimatedView`.

Comment: I'd like to test the direct superclass, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do

```
func testSuperclass() {
    val superclass = self.animatedView.superclass
    val expectedSuperclass = BREAnimatedView.class()
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(superclass, expectedSuperclass)
}
```

but I'd be glad to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Calling `class()` doesn't compile.